# Clipping with PNG in CSS

Tags: image, css, clip

Is there a way to clip the content of a div with an image overlay?

I've attempted to use: `background-clip` and something similar, but can't seem to figure it out!

Seen here:

https://codepen.io/brycesnyder/pen/pwdoWW

I only want the red to be displayed within the gray image area.

Comment: Use an image editor to make the outside transparent area of the shield image the same as your content background (usually white)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with experimental technologies.

To utilize an image as a clipping path for various things, you can use the property: "mask"

seen here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask

Though, you will need to prefix it.

Answer (score 0):

It would take a fair bit of tweaking to find the exact shape, but you can use the principles here - https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ - especially the border-width and border-radius properties - to "shape" the div.

If I were you, I'd start with a combination of:

- diamond
- egg
- cone

(all shapes that are shown / css shared on that css-tricks link above.)